# ES6 template string not working with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to fetch some data from my Mongo DB database and after fetching I am trying to add a property to that using ES6 template string and send that back to the user. But I see the code inside the template string is not getting evaluated could anyone please help me.

below is my code

```
Books.find(query)
    .then(books => {
        const bookToDisplay = books.map(books => {
            const newBook = books.toJSON();
            newBook.links = {};
            newBook.links.self = `http//${req.headers.host}/api/book${book._id}`;
            return newBook;
        })
        // res.json(books);
        res.json(bookToDisplay);
    })
    .catch(error => res.send(error));
```

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `book._id` but it does not exists. In your `books.map()` you are using `books` again. It should be like this: `books.map(book => { ... })`.